# Unequal measurements

Tags: statistics

> Let $\mathbf W \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times m}([0, 1])$ be a full-rank matrix ($n\geq m$). Suppose the following equality holds:
>   $$\mathbf y = \mathbf W \mathbf x,$$
>   where $\mathbf x, \mathbf y$ are vector-valued functions (particulary, CDFs). Given 
>   $$\hat{\mathbf y} = \mathbf y + \boldsymbol \varepsilon,$$
>   where $\mathbb E \boldsymbol \varepsilon = \mathbf 0, \mathbb V\boldsymbol \varepsilon < \infty$ I wish to estimate $\mathbf x$.

To be more precise, I have a sample $\mathcal X = (X_{ij}\mid i=1,\ldots , n; j=1,\ldots ,n_i)$ of independent random variables, where the variables $(X_{\ell j})$ are identically distributed for each fixed $\ell$. I use subsample of $\mathcal X$ to estimate $\mathbf y$: 
$$\hat y_\ell (t) = \hat y_\ell (t\mid X_{\ell 1}, \ldots , X_{\ell n_\ell}), \quad \ell=1, \ldots ,n.$$
In case all $\mathbb V\hat y_\ell$ are equal, it seems like the following estimator is optimal:
$$\hat {\mathbf x} = \mathbf W^\dagger \hat {\mathbf y},$$
where $\mathbf W^\dagger $ is a Moore-Penrose inverse of $\mathbf W$. However, in general case I think there should be a *weight* of each $\hat y_\ell$ corresponding to an *accuracy* of the estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use *weighted linear regression* with weights inverse to $\hat {\mathbf y}$'s variance:
$$\boldsymbol\Sigma = \mathbb V (\mathbf y + \boldsymbol \varepsilon )= \operatorname{diag}(\mathbb V\varepsilon _1, \ldots ,\mathbb V \varepsilon _n)$$
That is 
$$\hat{\mathbf x} = (\mathbf W ^\top \boldsymbol\Sigma ^{-1}\mathbf W)^{-1}\mathbf W ^\top \boldsymbol\Sigma ^{-1} \hat{\mathbf y}$$
As long as $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ depends on (unknown) $\mathbf y$ one can replace it with its estimator $\hat{\boldsymbol\Sigma} = \hat{\boldsymbol\Sigma}(t\mid \mathcal X)$.